# Extract and replace text matching multi-line pattern after keyword

Tags: python, regex, yaml

I am trying to transform a yaml document in order to make it easier to parse later in my project. I have output that looks like this:

I want to use regex to find all occurrences of:

```
  Export:
     Name: xxxxx
```

But only those occurrences which appear after "**Output:**"

My document looks something like this:

```
Resources: 
  MyResource: Resource 1
  Export: 
    Name: Some undesired export name
Outputs:
  ExportOne:
    Description: Notes about export #1 here
    Export:
      Name: Desired export #1
  ExportTwo: 
    Description: Notes about export #2 here
    Export:
      Name: Desired export #2
```

So far no matter what I have tried I only capture one of the "Export: Name:" occurrences.

After finding the aforementioned text my goal is to change it to

```
ExportName: <existing value>
```

I am using python for this project, so far the regular expressions I have tried have all been variations of:

```
(?s)(?<=Outputs:)(.+(Export:.*?Name:)+)
```

Any advice on how to do this... or a better way to perform this transformation?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe try something like this: `Export:\s+Name: (?P<name>.+)(?![\s\S]+^Outputs:)` see here: https://regex101.com/r/gIDDuD/latest. This assumes that there is only one "Outputs" statement.

Comment: You need space here in the yaml `MyResource: Res1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose from your tags that the input file is YAML. It would be better to use a YAML library for parsing and modifying the file. Using regular expressions is also possible, but not the best solution for me.

You have a missing space in your input file "MyResource: Res1".

Here is an example:

```
pip install pyyaml
```

```
import yaml

# Read from a file
def read_yaml(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        yaml_data = yaml.safe_load(file)
        return yaml_data


# Find and replace values
def modify_data(yaml_data):
    for output in yaml_data['Outputs'].values():
        if 'Export' in output and 'Name' in output['Export']:
            name = output['Export']['Name']
            output['ExportName'] = name
            del output['Export']
    return yaml_data

# Write to a file
def save_yaml(filename, yaml_data):
    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        yaml.dump(yaml_data, file, sort_keys=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = read_yaml('input.yaml')
    modified_data = modify_data(data)
    save_yaml('output.yaml', modified_data)
```

```
python main.py && cat output.yaml
Resources:
  MyResource: Res1
  Export:
    Name: SomeName
Outputs:
  ExportOne:
    ExportName: abc
  ExportTwo:
    ExportName: def
```

If you need to parse YAML v1.2 or later check the @Anthon answer.

Other yaml parsers that can be used: ruamel.yaml, strictyaml, poyo

Comment: You should point out that PyYAML that you are using only supports YAML 1.1 (outdated 15 years ago), that it reorders the keys of mappings and that if the real input contains comments, using PyYAML would drop them. The way you use it you would also give problems with  non-ASCII characters in the input. By providing that information, the OP can decide if using your code is a better option than using regular expressions and not encounter unexpected problems later on.

Comment: Good comment. The reordering keys are fixed.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendations. I think this is the better approach and the approach I will use.

Answer (score 0):

First of all please note that the document you present is invalid YAML, I assumed there is a space missing after
the colon in `MyResource:Res1`

Although you can change YAML documents using regular expressions, it is very easy
to create something that is no longer a valid YAML document.
This might occur (depending on the matching and rewriting) if there is an end-of-line
comment after `Export:`, and would also occur
the value for the key `Export` is a mapping with more than just the key 'Name'.

Using an file `input.yaml`:

```yaml
Resources: 
  MyResource: Res1
  Export: 
    Name: SomeName
Outputs:
  ExportOne:
    Export:  # this collapses to ExportName
      Name: abc
  ExportTwo:
    # this cannot be collapsed as
    #    ExportName: def
    #      extra: 42
    # is invalid yaml 
    Export:  
      Name: "def"
      extra: 42
```

I would load the YAML file and then recursively walk over the loaded data structure and only update
dictionaries with exactly the key `Export` and a value that is again
a dictionary with exactly one key `Name`:

```py
import sys
import pathlib
import ruamel.yaml

input = pathlib.Path('input.yaml')

def collapse(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        update = False
        for k, v in d.items():
            if (k == 'Export' and isinstance(v, dict)
                 and len(v) == 1 and 'Name' in v):
                update = True
            collapse(v)
        if update:
            d['ExportName'] = d['Export']['Name']
            del d['Export']
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for item in d:
            collapse(item)

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(input)

collapse(data)

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
Resources:
  MyResource: Res1
  ExportName: SomeName
Outputs:
  ExportOne:
    ExportName: abc
  ExportTwo:
    # this cannot be collapsed as
    #    ExportName: def
    #      extra: 42
    # is invalid yaml 
    Export:
      Name: "def"
      extra: 42
```

Given this to start with, it should be easy to follow different strategies if the value for `Export` is a multi-key dictionary, the dumping will take care of creating the valid YAML document.